# cypher query on unmanaged extension neo4j

Tags: java, neo4j, cypher

i have an unmanaged extension for my neo4j server.

and the code like the following.

```
@Path("/helloworld")
public class HelloWorldResource {

    private final GraphDatabaseService database;

    public HelloWorldResource(@Context GraphDatabaseService database) {
        this.database = database;
    }

   @GET
   @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
   @Path("/{nodeId}")
   public Response hello(@PathParam("nodeId") long nodeId) {
        String res = ""; 

        try ( Transaction ignored = database.beginTx();)
        {
            //@@problem
            Result result = database.execute( "MATCH (n:KISI) where id(n)=1 return n" );

        } catch (Exception e) {
            res = "Error = " + e.getMessage();
        }

        return Response
            .status(Status.OK)
            .entity(("nodeId =" + nodeId + " " + res).getBytes(Charset
                    .forName("UTF-8"))).build();
    }
}
```

When i deploy the code i got 500 internal error. 
if i remove the code

> Result result = database.execute( "MATCH (n:KISI) where id(n)=1 return
>   n" );

then everything is fine.

i checked the log file and the error is the following

> Aug 13, 2015 3:34:36 AM com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse
>   mapMappableContainerException SEVERE: The exception contained within
>   MappableContainerException could not be mapped to a response,
>   re-throwing to the HTTP container
>   java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   org.neo4j.graphdb.GraphDatabaseService.execute(Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/neo4j/graphdb/Result;
>     at
>   org.neo4j.examples.server.unmanaged.HelloWorldResource.hello(HelloWorldResource.java:55)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at
>   com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$ResponseOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:205)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
>     at
>   org.neo4j.server.rest.transactional.TransactionalRequestDispatcher.dispatch(TransactionalRequestDispatcher.java:139)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:288)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1469)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1400)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1349)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1339)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:416)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:537)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:699)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:698)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:505)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:211)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1096)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:432)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:175)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1030)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:136)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerList.handle(HandlerList.java:52)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:445)  at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:268)     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:229)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.run(AbstractConnection.java:358)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:601)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:532)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

so whats wrong with my code?

Comment: Please look into the log files. There should be whole stacktrace.

Comment: @MicTech i added the error exp on log file

Comment: First, you should add ignored.success(); after execute().

Comment: Is the Cypher query correct? Try it in web interface of Neo4j.

Comment: @MicTech yes the query is correct and i added ignored.success(), same result

Comment: suspicion: you've wrote your code against Neo4j 2.2.x and deployed it to a Neo4j 2.1.x (or earlier) server. `graphDb.execute()` has been added in 2.2 afaik.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess that your Neo4j distribution version and maven dependency version in pom.xml are not same.

But there are several things to check:

1) You should always close `Result` object.
Example:

```
try(Result result = database.execute( "MATCH (n:KISI) where id(n)=1 return n" )) {
    // do stuff here
}
```

```

2) Exception occurs not in `try-catch` but later. You should change your code to this:

```
try ( Transaction tx = database.beginTx()) {
    String query = "MATCH (n:KISI) where id(n)=1 return n";
    // use result with try-with-resource to ensure that it will be closed
    try(Result result = database.execute(query)) {
        // do stuff you need with result here
        return Response.ok("nodeId =" + nodeId).build();
    }

    tx.success(); // mark transaction as successful 
} catch (Exception e) {
    // If exception occurs - send exception message with 500 status code
    // It's good idea to write Exception stacktrace to log there
    return Response.serverError().entity(e.getMessage()).build()      
}
```

3) You should check how unmanaged extension `.jar` file is build.

- All Neo4j dependencies should be `provided` in pom.xml (there are already there in Neo4j distribution).
- Check that your database version and your dependency version in pom.xml are same. `GraphDatabaseService::execute` method is invented recently (2.2.3 if I remember correctly). Probably your database distribution is older than your maven dependencies.

Comment: now i am using neo4j 2.2.4 (i was using 2.1.6) and everything is fine. thanks a lot